# Can I throttle page pre-rendering with Next.js?

Tags: next.js, throttling

I'm working on a website with a few static pages pre-rendered by Next.js

I need to make many API requests within `getStaticPaths` just to know what pages actually exist on the backend, in addition to at least one API request per page to get the actual data, so the build process is triggering quite a few calls to the backend in rapid succession. This seems to be a problem.

It seems I'm reaching some kind of limit on my backend because at some point I start getting errors like `507 Insufficient Storage` coming back instead of the expected API response.

My theory is that my very cheap shared hosting plan just can't handle all these requests in such a short period of time, so I was wondering if Next.js had any throttling mechanism I could use to give the backend some breathing room.

I guess I can implement throttling myself for the requests that I control, within `getStaticPaths`, but if that's not enough, I wonder how I could throttle the requests made by Next.js for each path I return…

Clearly there are many other ways around my issue, including:

- Using a better CMS which doesn't consume as much resources to answer API calls
- Getting a hosting plan with more resources available
- Pre-rendering fewer pages and letting Next.js dynamically create the lesser-viewed pages on first visit

But my question remains nonetheless: Can requests performed by the Next.js pre-renderer be throttled?

Note that this could also be useful to work with backends that implement harsh rate-limiting…

Comment: I am not quite sure why you are making multiple API calls to check pages instead of having the backend perform that job, and return the valid page?

Comment: @Toxnyc great question. That's because I am using a backend that is also a CMS and which I didn't build and cannot modify as much as I'd like. Otherwise, I would indeed do exactly that. In fact, I may find a way to do so with that backend, but that hasn't happened yet. In any case, I'm still interested to know whether the requests performed by Next.js to pre-render pages can be throttled.

Comment: This might do: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#when-is-fallback-true-useful

Comment: Thanks @brc-dd. I use incremental static generation with a relatively short revalidation period to make sure users can quickly see any updates made to a page via the CMS backend, so I don't think this is the right solution for me since `fallback: true` doesn't _update_ generated pages. Still, it's a good thing to point out for anybody else reading this.

Comment: `fallback: true` and incremental static regeneration are not mutually exclusive - you can have both at the same time. Having `fallback: true` enables you to _not_ generate all your pages at build time.

Comment: @juliomalves Are you sure?
From: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#when-is-fallback-true-useful : "`fallback: true` will not update generated pages, for that take a look at [Incremental Static Regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration)."

Comment: Yes, that's correct - it will not _update_ existing pages, but it will _generate_ new pages. I'm not suggesting to _only_ use `fallback: true`, I'm saying you could use both at the same time.